# I can't do a function call from another module

Tags: python, object, module

Im new to python and I want to print out the results from my add.py script on to my main.py script but I get an error 
"line 2, in  print(add())TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

main.py

```
import add
print(add())
```

add.py

```
class sample:
    def addition(self):
        add = 1+1
        return add
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change  `main.py` to:

```
import add
print(add.sample().addition())
```

Please note in the second line:

`add` is the name of the module (file)

`sample` is the name of the class in the module. The parentheses are added to create a new instance of the class.

`addition` is the name of the method within the class

So in this line you are basically saying: Create a new instance of the class `sample` in the `add` module, then call the `addition` function on it.

The `add` variable in your `addition` function cannot be used outside of the function, because it's a [local variable](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables#local-variables).

Comment: It works, thanks for the help and good explanation.

Comment: @Sev If you found this helpful, please accept the answer.